# Ho to deal with images saved localy in cache when you update a website?

Tags: php, web-applications, image-processing, web, ftp

When i upload new content to my webpage example New images , when i connect to the webpage i still see the old images even though when i look in the code i see the new content.

I suspect that the content stays cached locally on my browser so only when the cache gets full or is cleaned i see the new content .

Can anyone tell me if it's possible to allow for users to see the new content i upload immediately after i upload it without them having to clear the cache.

Can i disable it for local users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is, whenever you modify the file, you give it a new filename.

Alternatively you can append a timestamp.  A crude version is like this:

```
<img src="images/foo.gif?t=<?php echo time(); ?>" />
```

However this will cause the image to be reloaded every time.  A better version is:

```
<img src="images/foo.gif?t=<?php echo filemtime($siteRootDir . '/images/foo.gif'); ?>" />
```

This will print the modification timestamp of the file itself, so a new version will only be requested when the file is actually modified.  Obviously `$siteRootDir` must have a relevant value.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a simple `?<?php echo time();?>` to the end of the url in the `<img/>` tag, but this will force the page to reload the image every time.. not just when you update them.

Answer (score 1):

A common way is to add a GET-string behind your image calls.

Set the string somewhere in your config:

```
<?php $version = "xyz123"; ?>
```

Now add the string to your image, script or css calls:

```
<img src="path/to/image.png?<?php echo $version; ?>"/>
```

Whenever you change your stuff modify the version-string to force the update of the external files.

Comment: You're going to do this for every single image?  Or just one string so when it changes, every image in the site is re-requested?

Comment: One string in the config-file which is modified every time you update your code. It's a one-time-job to add the "echo $version" snippet to every image-call though.

Comment: Interesting, I've never seen this. If you're okay with this forcing every image in the site to be reloaded by every client, whenever any one image is updated, I don't see why not.  (I guess that would depend how many images you are using and how dynamic they generally are).

Comment: Well, sort of standard solution for simple-browser-cache-invalidation. Drupal act that way for css and javascript files. And it's only loading the images once after a update - unlike the time(); solution above.
If you're dealing with lot's of images there should be a dedicated image-cache-handler which checks the cache status of every asset by request.

Comment: Yep definitely agree this is better than just appending the current timestamp to every image.

Answer (score 0):

What I do is append the time function to the end of the URL for the image so it is dynamically hit every time for each user. e.g.:

```
echo '<img src="images/image.jpg?' . time() . '" alt="">';
```

Comment: To disable it for local users put an IF condition to check the substring of the IP network range. Use the $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] global variable.